# How to share NSManagedObject array between threads

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an app where I am storing contacts to core data , on every launch app loads these contacts to an array of NSManagedObject. Now whenever I try to read from this array for some purpose app crashes, I am trying to read the entire array and check for some data disparity. Problem is this array will be huge and I want to do this task in background so that UI doesn't get blocked, but every time I run the code which modifies some objects from this array Xcode asserts and stops app. I have enabled -com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1 flag in scheme to enable multi threading related assertion.
Now how can i do the above task in background ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch this array in background thread with appropriate NSManagedObjectContext. You can check this tutorial for more info: https://www.raywenderlich.com/145877/core-data-tutorial-multiple-managed-object-contexts-2